# How ActivateTab in Outlook

Tags: .net, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm using VSTO 4 with .NET 4.6.1 successfully in Outlook, using XML custom ribbon.

Is there any way to select my Ribbon.Tab programmatically from ThisAddIn code (and not from Ribbon-code)?

I need to change Outlook to my tab if some text appears in a message. When the user open the message, the focus must change to my own TAB (eg. from Message to MyTab).

I can call "myRibbon.MyOwnRibbon.ActivateTab" or "ActivateTabQ" but both functions I get an error like "value does not fall within the expected range".

If I call "ActivateTabMso" (which force me to use the idMso-name = "TabAddIns") I got no error but no action at all - the tab is not selected

I had seen hundreds of articles and Microsoft Help but most of them are related to VBA and Excel/Word - not a .NET Add-In to OUtlook 2013-2016

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: What value do you pass to the `ActivateTab` method? Is it the ID of your custom ribbon tab?

Comment: Yes, the ID of my tab. I tried either select it using idMso (TabAddIns) as the custom ID (in this case, without idMso caused problems related to use idMso and ID)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [ActivateTab](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Office-Shared-VBA/articles/iribbonui-activatetab-method-office) method of the `IRibbonUI` interface. See [Ribbon Extensibility in Office 2010: Tab Activation and Auto-Scaling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691834%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for more information. The parameter specifies the Id of the custom Ribbon tab to be activated.

Comment: It was exactly what I utilized. But I need it in the "THisAddIn" code and not in the Ribbon code.  I'm also using XML version (customized ribbon).